# How to create a personal map with Google Maps and navigate with Street View?

Tags: google-maps

How can I create a new map (with my personal POIs) using Google Maps from a PC browser and use Street View options to see details?

I am not able to create a map, give a name and add new points.

I need to use it from a smartphone but I prefer to create it by PC because of the screen dimensions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a new map is it necassary to login with your personal google account and BEFORE any search you can see the menu where you can find your maps and create new ones

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have used is to create the new map in one browser window
(Sign in and click in the search bar:  doing this shows a My Maps link - clicking this gives a Create link.  Clicking this opens a new personal map editing window.)

And use street-view in another browser tab.

This is tedious, because you have to locate particular spots on one, and then find them on the other from the map features (bends, crossroad and the like).   But I have not found Street View in the MyMaps editor tool.